# What is the best way to make reports in ASP.NET CORE (using ABP's Framework) + ANGULAR 7 APP

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, reporting

I need some recomendation about reporting tools or something where I can do reports for an application, I've investigated but I don't find for something good to do it, I hope you can help me.

What I mean is for example print a List of Articles, Profits vs. Losses And everything I want to show to the client.

In desktop applications I used to use Crystal-Reports, I'm looking for something like this for web.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [ngx-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) might give you a head-start in terms of front-end components for the Angular app, but given each client has different needs for reporting you would need to tailor your business logic and auth in .NET Core to that.

I suggest look for “business intelligence” systems that have the features you need and see if any of them have a library you can use to embed components. These would likely have additional ongoing costs.